# R split string based on conditions

Tags: r

I would like to split the Following string

```
c1 <- c("10033  EXPLOITATION 16 0034 SODIRIB 16")
```

into two columns based on the condition

> If a white space is followed and preceded split the string.

Here I would like to obtain the following split :

```
A1                                     A2
"10033 EXPLOITATION 16"                "0034 SODIRIB 16"
```

I tried the following code :

```
res <- strsplit(c1, "[0-9]\\s{2,}[0-9]")
```

Comment: Don't quite understand the logic for splitting. You said split when "white space is followed and preceded...", but why are you splitting at the space following "16" and not the other spaces? Did you mean to say split on a space when "followed and preceded by a digit"?

Comment: Hi, Thank for your answer. Yes I mean "Split on a space when "followed and preceded by a digit"

Answer (score 1):

We could use the folowwing. This assumes the numbers following a space do not have a length of 2.

```
strsplit(c1,"\\s(?=[0-9]{3,})",perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "10033  EXPLOITATION 16" "0034 SODIRIB 16"
```